# XSLT Transform to remove namespaces from all elements, then specify namespace on one

Tags: xslt

I need to transform this XML and remove all the namespaces.

However I need a new namespace on any element named Id only if it is child of CompanyKey.

Additionally, if easily done, remove the highest level element.

I need it to work in XSLT 2.0.  I think I can do most of this with separate transforms but it would be best if it all worked in one.

If changing the alias ns1 to mean a different namespace in the output is problematic, I could use a completely different one like 'xyz'.

Here is the source XML:

```
<tns:DynamicsGP_CreateSalesOrder_In xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Dynamics.Common" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Dynamics.GP" >
    <tns:salesOrder>
        <ns1:Key>
            <ns1:CompanyKey>
                <tns:Id>2</tns:Id>
            </ns1:CompanyKey>
            <ns1:Id>WorkOrder1</ns1:Id>
        </ns1:Key>
        <ns1:Date>2019-12-31</ns1:Date>
        <ns1:DocumentTypeKey>
            <ns1:CompanyKey>
                <tns:Id>2</tns:Id>
            </ns1:CompanyKey>
            <ns1:Id>STDWORD</ns1:Id>
            <ns1:Type>Order</ns1:Type>
        </ns1:DocumentTypeKey>
        <ns1:Lines>
            <ns1:SalesOrderLine>
                <ns1:ItemKey>
                    <ns1:CompanyKey>
                        <tns:Id>2</tns:Id>
                    </ns1:CompanyKey>
                    <ns1:Id>WPT</ns1:Id>
                </ns1:ItemKey>
            </ns1:SalesOrderLine>
        </ns1:Lines>
    </tns:salesOrder></tns:DynamicsGP_CreateSalesOrder_In>
```

Desired output:

```
<salesOrder xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/01">
<Key>
    <CompanyKey>
        <ns1:Id>2</ns1:Id>
    </CompanyKey>
    <Id>WorkOrder1</Id>
</Key>
<Date>2019-12-31</Date>
<DocumentTypeKey>
    <CompanyKey>
        <ns1:Id>2</ns1:Id>
    </CompanyKey>
    <Id>STDWORD</Id>
    <Type>Order</Type>
</DocumentTypeKey>
<Lines>
    <SalesOrderLine>
        <ItemKey>
            <CompanyKey>
                <ns1:Id>2</ns1:Id>
            </CompanyKey>
            <Id>WPT</Id>
        </ItemKey>
    </SalesOrderLine>
</Lines></salesOrder>
```

This is my current attempt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/01">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Id">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="ns1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Going by your output, you also want to remove the `DynamicsGP_CreateSalesOrder_In` top wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work for you:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Dynamics.Common"
xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/01"
exclude-result-prefixes="tns">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- remove all namespaces -->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove top wrapper -->
<xsl:template match="/tns:DynamicsGP_CreateSalesOrder_In">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- declare new namespace on root element -->
<xsl:template match="tns:salesOrder">
     <salesOrder xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/01">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </salesOrder>
</xsl:template>

<!-- change namespace on some elements -->
<xsl:template match="tns:Id">
     <ns1:Id>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </ns1:Id>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZWE/1

---

Note that the third template is optional and for cosmetic purposes only; if you remove it, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<salesOrder>
   <Key>
      <CompanyKey>
         <ns1:Id xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/01">2</ns1:Id>
      </CompanyKey>
      <Id>WorkOrder1</Id>
   </Key>
   <Date>2019-12-31</Date>
   <DocumentTypeKey>
      <CompanyKey>
         <ns1:Id xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/01">2</ns1:Id>
      </CompanyKey>
      <Id>STDWORD</Id>
      <Type>Order</Type>
   </DocumentTypeKey>
   <Lines>
      <SalesOrderLine>
         <ItemKey>
            <CompanyKey>
               <ns1:Id xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/01">2</ns1:Id>
            </CompanyKey>
            <Id>WPT</Id>
         </ItemKey>
      </SalesOrderLine>
   </Lines>
</salesOrder>
```

which is semantically identical to the requested output.

Comment: Thank you, Michael, it looks like that will do exactly what I need!  I'll try to make the root element dynamic because /tns:DynamicsGP_CreateSalesOrder_In is for one use case, but I'd like it to be universal.

Comment: That should be easy to do by making the 2nd template `match="/*"`.